# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/social/add ProfileSocialMedia has no profile

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to use the clean method of a model in my project, but I get the error:

```py
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/social/add
ProfileSocialMedia has no profile.
```

I've tried a lot of different things, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

What I want to do is, this class is associated with a profile and also with a social profile, where the identification field will be a number or a link to a profile on a social network, before saving the data I want to do some checks

the check that is generating the problem is apparently the `clean_social_media def` in `print(profile)`

If I delete this check the error occurs in other cleans, which makes me think that perhaps the profile is not being passed correctly.

In this check, basically I want to block the creation of an object from the `ProfileSocialMedia` model if the profile I am creating already has 6 or more social networks created.

Everything works, it saves correctly, but when it reaches the limit (6) it generates the error
Precisely for this reason I have more doubts, because when it reaches the limit the error is generated?

Below is my code

```py
class ProfileSocialMedia(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name="medias", `enter code here`on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    social_media = models.ForeignKey(SocialMedia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    identification = models.CharField("Identification", max_length=3000)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Profile Owner: {self.profile.user.first_name} / Social Media: {self.social_media.name}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Profile Social Media'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Profile Social Medias'
    
    def clean_social_media(self):
        if self.social_media is None:
            raise ValidationError("Por favor, selecione uma rede social")
        print(self.profile)
    

    def clean_identification(self):
        if self.social_media.is_link == False:
            validate_number(self.identification)
        else:
            validate_url(self.identification)
    
    def clean_socials(self):
        limit = 6
        socials = self.profile.medias.all()
        if socials.count() >= limit:
            raise ValidationError("Você atingiu o limite(6) de redes socias que podem ser adicionadas, altere ou exclua uma rede social existente.")

    def clean(self):
        self.clean_identification()
        self.clean_social_media()
        self.clean_socials()
        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.social_media.is_link:
            if not re.match(r'^https?://', self.identification):
                self.identification = f'https://{self.identification}'
        self.full_clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class AddSocialMediaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    social_media = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=True, label='Escolha uma rede social', empty_label=None, queryset=SocialMedia.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'update-form'}))
    identification = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Identificação da rede social', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'update-form'}), help_text='Insira o número para adicionar o whatsapp no formato cód país + ddd + número, ex: (+55)24981094563 ou link do perfil para todas as outras redes.')
 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.profile = kwargs.pop('profile', None)
        super(AddSocialMediaForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     
    class Meta:
        model = ProfileSocialMedia
        fields = ('social_media', 'identification')


class AddSocialMediaView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'add_social_media.html'

    def post(self, request):
        profile_user = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
        form = AddSocialMediaForm(data=request.POST or None, profile=profile_user)
        message_save_data_successfully = "Os seus dados foram atualizados."
        message_auth_error = 'Você precisa estar autenticado para acessar esta página, portanto, será redirecionado para a página inicial após 5 segundos.'
        
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if form.is_valid():
                social_media = form.save(commit=False)
                social_media.profile = profile_user 
                social_media.save() 
            else:
                return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
        else:
            messages.error(request, (message_auth_error), extra_tags='message_auth_error')
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'message_auth_error':message_auth_error})
        
        messages.success(request, (message_save_data_successfully), extra_tags='message_save_data_successfully')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'message_save_data_successfully':message_save_data_successfully})


    def get(self, request):
        profile_user = Profile.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id)
        form = AddSocialMediaForm(data=request.GET or None, profile=profile_user)
        message_auth_error = 'Você precisa estar autenticado para acessar esta página, portanto, será redirecionado para a página inicial após 5 segundos.'
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
        else:
            messages.error(request, (message_auth_error), extra_tags='message_auth_error')
            return render(request, self.template_name, {'message_auth_error':message_auth_error})
```

I want the clean method to work correctly, I'm implementing it in the model because I want it to work regardless of where I'm sending the data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In simple terms, I want to simply run the clean_socials function on the model, but I get the error
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist in /profile/social/add ProfileSocialMedia has no profile.
For some reason.
This clean_socials method basically adds a limit of objects of this class for each user in the system, that is, each user can only instantiate only 6 objects of the ProfileSocialMedia class, until the limit the addition works correctly, when a user reaches this limit, it generates the error